# write video stream to HTTP response while the video is downloading get error: ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: servlets, video-streaming, socketexception

I need to play video in brower, I use VLC plugin to send request to a servlet, in the servlet I write the video stream to response, but when the video is downloading, every time I get:

> ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Through `FileChannel size()` I can see the video size is increasing, even to it's full size, but after a while I still got the error. Can anyone help me?

Exception info:

```
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:401)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:449)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:349)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:424)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:413)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:89)
at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Channels.java:296)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferToArbitraryChannel(FileChannelImpl.java:465)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo(FileChannelImpl.java:514)
at com.certus.isa.server.servlet.PlayServlet.doGet(PlayServlet.java:66)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
at com.certus.isa.server.service.security.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181)
at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285)
at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:96)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:726)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:449)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:750)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:118)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:559)
at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:567)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:396)
... 33 more
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:401)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:449)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:340)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:299)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.close(CoyoteOutputStream.java:104)
at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.implCloseChannel(Channels.java:307)
at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.close(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:97)
at com.certus.isa.server.servlet.PlayServlet.doGet(PlayServlet.java:80)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
at com.certus.isa.server.service.security.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181)
at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285)
at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:726)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:449)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:750)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:118)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:559)
at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:567)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:396)
... 31 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser has closed the connection so the server got a connection reset. So you need to look into why the browser closed it.

Comment: The problem is solved, I have to tell the brower the total length of the video. Thanks.     response.setHeader("Content-Length", totalLengthOfVideo);

Comment: @Luna You should use `setContentLength()` for that.